# Push is not working in node js

Tags: json, node.js, express, ejs

Here is the code

```
loginController.prototype.newUserValidation = function(name,email,username,password, callback){ 
    var errorMessage = {};
    var name = validator.trim(name);
    var email =validator.trim(email);
    var username = validator.trim(username);
    var password = validator.trim(password);

    if(!validator.isLength(name,1)){
         errorMessage.push("Name is required field");
    }
    if(!validator.isLength(email,1)){
        errorMessage.push("Email is required field");   
    } else if(!validator.isEmail(email)){
         errorMessage.push("Email is not valid");   
    }
    if(!validator.isLength(username,1)){
         errorMessage.push("username is required field");
    }
    if(!validator.isLength(password,1)){
         errorMessage.push("password is required field");
    }
    callback(errorMessage); 
}
```

This error is coming :

Object # has no method 'push'

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'
    at Database.loginController.newUserValidation (/home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/controller/login-controller.js:49:16)
    at module.exports (/home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/routes/index.js:166:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/vinove/Desktop/AshutoshJha/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an object:

```
var errorMessage = {};
```

An object is a set of key/value pairs:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "age" : 21
}
```

If you want to be able to add random data to your variable, you need an array:

```
var errorMessage = [];
```

Then your code would work

Answer (score 0):

the push method is available for array datatype.
In your code you are defining json
i.e `var errorMessage={}`. 
internally it is json.
Thats why it showing error `Object # has no method 'push'`

so too get rid of this error just change

```
var errorMessage = {};
```

to

```
var errorMessage = [];
```